# catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when no selected row (-1) after pressen a key

Tags: java, try-catch

hello guys this is my first question
if no row selected i want to catch that and display a message..

```
private void table_Order_EKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
          int row = table_Order_E.getSelectedRow();

             if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT)
             {

             }

             try{

             if ( evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE && row<0 )
             {

                 System.err.println("No Row has been selected..."+row);

             }else if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE && row >-1)
             {
                 model.removeRow(row);//remov with delete key.

             }
             }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
             }
        }
```

Comment: but my question is different !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a if condition and throw an exception from your try block.
Please refer http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/throw-in-java/ for further reference

Comment: solved thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

here is the updating of my code also there was an exception outside the try i moved the declaration of row inside the try and the problem solved thank u.

```
private void table_Order_EKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         

try{
     int row = table_Order_E.getSelectedRow();//the exception may be here.

        if (row >=0 && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT) {
             model.addRow(rowData);//add with insert key
        }else if(row<0 && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT ){
            System.err.println("No Row insert..!");
        }

        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE && row < 0) {

        } else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE && row > -1) {
            model.removeRow(row);//remov with delete key.

        }

}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Choose a Row To Delete..");
    }
    else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_INSERT ){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Click Inside The Table To Add new Row..");
    }
    }
    }
```